# jQuery hover function after window resize cannot be changed into click function

Tags: jquery, function, hover, click, dropdown

I have made a menu with two states in mind - on size greater or equal than 1025px, the dropdown submenus are opened by hovering on them and that is fine, on the other side, on size less than 1025px, the the submenus are opened by clicking on them. The problem is on the latter case, when resizing the browser at less than 1025px size, the hovering function still prevails, and only after refreshing the browser, the clicking function comes into action and everything is fine until I resize the browser again at greater than 1025px size and then when again resize it at less then 1025px size.

I would appreciate some help.

Thanks,

CP

```js
$(function() {
  var isMobile = false;
  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1025) {
      isMobile = false;
      $('nav li').hover(
        function() {
          $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(150);
        });
    } else {
      isMobile = true;
      $("nav li").click(function() {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(150);
      });
    };
  });
  $(window).resize(); // Trigger window resize to check on load
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,500);

/* main Styles */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: #fafafa;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}


/* Navigation Styles */

nav {
  background: #2ba0db;
}

nav ul {
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px 14px;
  transition: 0.08s linear;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #126d9b;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #2ba0db;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  background: #373737;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 14px;
}

nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  background: #126d9b;
}

nav .fa.fa-angle-down {
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">Categories<i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Category One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Services<i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Service One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Five</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Six</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never removing the old event handlers when the browser resizes, you're just adding more event handlers each time. When one of these events happens, it executes all the handlers.

Rather than binding event handlers inside the `.resize()` handler, bind them once and have them check the `isMobile` variable to decide whether to do anything.

```js
$(function() {
  var isMobile = false;
  $('nav li').hover(function() {
    if (!isMobile) {
      $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(150);
    }
  }).click(function() {
    if (isMobile) {
      $('ul', this).stop().slideToggle(150);
    }
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    isMobile = $(window).width() < 1025;
  });
  $(window).resize(); // Trigger window resize to check on load
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,500);

/* main Styles */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: #fafafa;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}


/* Navigation Styles */

nav {
  background: #2ba0db;
}

nav ul {
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px 14px;
  transition: 0.08s linear;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #126d9b;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #2ba0db;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  border-top: 1px solid #444;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  background: #373737;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 14px;
}

nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  background: #126d9b;
}

nav .fa.fa-angle-down {
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">Categories<i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Category One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Services<i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Service One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Five</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Service Six</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```